# Dynamodb update based on id of nested array object

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have a user table with partition key of username as follows:

```
{
username: 1234,
experience:[
 {id: 322, title:"CTO", company:"google"},
 {id:432, title: CFO, company: "fb"}
]
}
```

...
I need to update experience of a person based on id.(e.g update experience with id of 322)

Could someone guide me how this could be done in dynamodb node js.

Comment: all experiences with that ID? Or you mean change experience with ID `322` for person `123`?

Comment: yes need to change experience of id 322 for username 1234

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not aware of a way in DynamoDB to manipulate lists based on the value of the list item. The below code changes the company value for employee 322 -- but it assumes you know the the array position of the employee in the list.

```
maps.put_item(
   Item={
    'PK': '1234',
    'experience': [
        {'id':322, 'title': 'CTO', 'company': 'google'},
        {'id':432, 'title': 'CFO', 'company': 'fb'}
    ]
   }
)

result = maps.update_item(
    Key={
        'PK': '1234'
    },
    UpdateExpression='SET experience[0] = :v1',
    ExpressionAttributeValues={':v1': {'id':322, 'title':'CTO', 'company':'amazon'} }
)
```